# Find tweets with specified hashtags and post onto webpage

Tags: javascript, json

I did some searching and found a post that informs how to find the hashtag, posted by user **gnab**.

> You can simply fetch http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23test to get a list of tweets containing #test in JSON, where %23test is #test URL encoded.

After I find the tweet I want to load it onto a page. This page would constantly refresh with the latest tweets that contain this hashtag. I've only just started using HTML, CSS and some jQuery so this is very new to me. How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, if you have a tweet account log on to your twitter account and click on settings and check out the widgets option.Create a new widget configure according to your wish and click on the add widget, you will get a piece of code just copy paste and put it in the iframe. You dont have to break your head for it.

Answer (score 0):

Look this snippet I made, I think it will bring you some ideas:

http://jsfiddle.net/TgTtV/

```
lastDate = false;
setInterval(function() {

  function compareDates (argument) {
    return (new Date(argument.created_at) > lastDate);
  }

   jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {q: encodeURIComponent('#test')},

      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          //If it's the first time running, prepend all tweets to the page
          if(!lastDate) {
            for(i in data.results) {
                $('body').prepend('<p>'+data.results[i].from_user+': '+data.results[i].text+'</p>');
            }
          } else { //Only new tweets, filtered by date are added
            var newMessages = data.results.filter(compareDates);
              //Just for test
              console.log(newMessages);
            for(i in newMessages) {
                $('body').prepend('<p>'+newMessages[i].from_user+': '+newMessages[i].text+'</p>');
            }
          }

          lastDate = new Date(data.results[0].created_at);
      }
    });

}, 10000);
```

Explanation:
The snippet first load a bunch of tweets from your query (in this case, the hashtag #test), and puts the username and the tweet content inside a paragraph. After the first load, it continues loading tweets, but filtering them by date using the compareDates function, and showing only new tweets in the page.
To understand better, I recommend you to test this snippet with Firebug's console open.